# How to send a http2 request via unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http2

I am looking for the library or sample code through which the http2 request could be sent from unity. I tried to do the same via UnityWebRequest but got this error:

**Curl error 1: Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed**

Please guide.

Comment: Any news on this one?
Not finding anything useful about UnityWebRequest and HTTP2 